# ng2-translate - The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ng2-translate

I am fixing my Karma configuration to run tests for  Angular2 - rc 1 version.
I can run the tests but they fail if I have a translate pipe within the html.
(The config I could get it to work I got it from [here][1])

my karma.conf

```
   module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    files: [
      // Polyfills.
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',

      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Zone.js dependencies
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs.
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false },
      { pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-translate/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},

      {pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true},

      // paths loaded via module imports
      // Angular itself
      // {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/router-deprecated/index.js', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      // {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular2-material/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      // Our built application code
      {pattern: 'dist/**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},

      // paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      {pattern: 'dist/**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: 'dist/**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

      {pattern: 'dist/assets/images/**/*.jpg', watched: false, included: false, served: true},
      {pattern: 'dist/assets/images/**/*.png', watched: false, included: false, served: true},
      {pattern: 'dist/assets/i18n/**/*.json', watched: false, included: false, served: true},
      {pattern: 'dist/local_config.json', watched: false, included: false, served: true},
      // paths to support debugging with source maps in dev tools
      // {pattern: 'src/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: true},
      //{pattern: 'dist/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // proxied base paths
    proxies: {
      // required for component assests fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": "/base/dist/app/",
      "/assets/": "/base/dist/assets/",
      "/i18n/": "/base/dist/assets/i18n/"
    },

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'node_modules/@angular/**/*spec.js'
    ],

    // // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'dist/**/!(*spec).js': ['coverage']
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter

    coverageReporter: {
        dir: 'coverage/',
        reporters: [
            { type: 'text-summary' },
            { type: 'json', subdir: '.', file: 'coverage-final.json' },
            { type: 'html' }
        ],
        instrumenterOptions: {
            istanbul: { noCompact: true }
        }
    },

    // reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  })
}
```

my karma-test-shim.js

```
    /*global jasmine, __karma__, window*/
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 1000;

__karma__.loaded = function () {
};

var distPath = '/base/';
var appPath = distPath;

function isJsFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-3) == '.js';
}

function isSpecFile(path) {
  return path.slice(-8) == '.spec.js';
}

function isAppFile(path) {
  return isJsFile(path) && (path.substr(0, appPath.length) == appPath);
}

var allSpecFiles = Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
  .filter(isSpecFile)
  .filter(isAppFile);

// Load our SystemJS configuration.
System.config({
   baseURL: distPath
});

System.import('systemjs.config.test.js').then(function() {
  // Load and configure the TestComponentBuilder.
  return Promise.all([
    System.import('@angular/core/testing'),
    System.import('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing')
  ]).then(function (providers) {
    var testing = providers[0];
    var testingBrowser = providers[1];

    testing.setBaseTestProviders(testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
      testingBrowser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
  });
}).then(function() {
  // Finally, load all spec files.
  // This will run the tests directly.
  return Promise.all(
    allSpecFiles.map(function (moduleName) {
      return System.import(moduleName);
    }));
}).then(__karma__.start, __karma__.error);


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178267/angular2-rc1-karma-error-unable-to-find-angular-core-testing
```

One of my tests :

...

```
import { TranslateService, TranslateLoader, TranslateStaticLoader} from 'ng2-translate';
import { TranslationService } from '../../services/localization/translation.service';
```

...
    describe('Login Messages', () => {

```
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        provide( CmsService, { useClass: MockCmsService }),
        provide(Config, { useClass: MockConfig }),
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(Router, { useClass: MockRouter }),
        TranslateService,
        // provide(TranslateService, { useClass: MockTranslateService }),
        // provide(TranslationService, { useClass: MockTranslationService }),
        TranslationService,
        SessionService,
        provide(TranslateLoader, {
            useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
            deps: [Http]
        }),
        ModuleLoaderService,
        MyGlobals
    ]);

    beforeEach(() => {
        Config.params = {
            fleetVersionNumber: 'xyz'
        };
    });

    fit('should display messgages', inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
        return tcb.createAsync(LoginMessages).then((componentFixture) => {
            componentFixture.componentInstance.messages = MESSAGES;
            let element = componentFixture.nativeElement;
            componentFixture.detectChanges();
            expect(element.querySelectorAll('.msg-row').length).toBe(3);

            expect(element.querySelectorAll('.msg-row')[0].querySelector('span').innerText).toBe('Plain bla bla');
```

....

The component html:

...

```
<div style="margin:0 5px 0 25px"><span [innerHTML]="msg.key | translate "></span></div>
```

...

The error I get when running Karma:

The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign msg-icon">
        ][innerHTML]="msg.key | translate ">
    
"): LoginMessages@6:47
Error: Template parse errors: ...

To mention that the translate pipe works ok within the actual app.
Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Nobody has a hint of how to configure Karma to see this pipe ? I feel I am so close ...

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer: It was not a Karma config issue.
In order the pipe to be seen within the component I needed to provide it in the test:

```
  beforeEachProviders(() => [
     ....
     provide(PLATFORM_PIPES, {useValue: TranslationPipe, multi:  true})
     ....
  ])
```

Comment: This is not working with Angular 2.1.0 unit testing. It is not recognizing PLATFORM_PIPES. Any help?

Comment: Here i wrote about how to do it with ngx. (Angular 4+) http://stackoverflow.com/a/43579026/356759