# The pipe 'translate' could not be found , angular2 component testing

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-testing, ng2-translate

I am working on component testing with angular2.
  in my html template i use the translate pipe.
  This is the code of the test :

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed ,getTestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { RightComponent } from './right.component';
import {TranslateService} from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import {Injector} from "@angular/core";
let comp:    RightComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<RightComponent>;
let el:      DebugElement;
let translate: TranslateService;
let injector: Injector;

describe('testComponent', () => {

beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ RightComponent ]
});

 injector = getTestBed();
 translate = injector.get(TranslateService);
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RightComponent);

comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

// get title DebugElement by element name
el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h2'));
});
it('should display original title', () => {
fixture.detectChanges(); // trigger data binding
expect(el.nativeElement.textContent).toContain('Liste des droits');
});

});
```

i got this error the the translate pipe is not known :

```
Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("<h2>[ERROR ->]{{'RIGHT_TITLE' |      translate}}</h2>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="rightTableId" clas"): RightComponent@0:4
 The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("
  <table id="rightTableId" class="table table-striped">
     <tr>
         <th>[ERROR ->]{{'NAME_LABEL' | translate}}</th>
     </tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let right of rights">
 "): RightComponent@4:16
  The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("
     </tr>
     <tr *ngFor="let right of rights">
         <td>[ERROR ->]{{right.name | translate}}</td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

How we resolve this problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: is it a custom pipe or translation service by angular2?

Comment: it's the ng2-translate https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate

Answer (score 53):

> it's the ng2-translate [github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate)

You need to configure the `TestBed` with the library module just like you would configure the library with your real application. And looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate/blob/master/README.md), it shows configuring it by importing the module

```
imports: [
  TranslateModule.forRoot()
]
```

So you should do the same in the `TestBed` configuration

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ RightComponent ],
  imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()]
});
```

This is what the `TestBed.configureTestingModule` is for: to configure a module for the test environment.

Comment: This was killing me for hours. I was trying to test a component that uses the translate pipe. Tried importing the module without the .forRoot() and that did not work.

Comment: this answer got me to the right answer. However, by importing my PipesModule into the test suite I was importing a load of pipes I didn't need which slowed down the test run. By importing only the specific pipe I needed into the declarations section I got the best solution. Thanks for the guidance here.

Answer (score 7):

With latest Angular 4 compatible `ngx-translate` you need to implement this directly into the component you want to test:

```
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
import {Http, HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {
    MissingTranslationHandler,
    TranslateLoader,
    TranslateModule,
    TranslateService
} from "@ngx-translate/core";

...

export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: Http) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

   ...

   imports: [
                TranslateModule.forRoot({
                    loader: {
                        provide: TranslateLoader,
                        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                        deps: [Http]
                    }
                })
            ],
   ...

   providers: [
                TranslateService
   ...
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, but I just needed to add `{ provide: Http, useValue: true },` to `providers`

Answer (score 1):

```
beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [TranslateModule.forRoot()],
          declarations: [HeaderComponent],
          schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents(); 
  });
```

so it also helped me!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).